# RegEx and JavaScript: Pipes are getting left behind when group is replaced

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I'm trying to replace an entire variable within an expression. The variable is preceded by either a start-of-string character (carat) or a pipe, and proceeded by either an end-of-string character (dollar sign) or a pipe. I need to replace the **entire variable**, including preceding and proceeding characters, with a pipe. I have the following code to capture the variable:

```
fullVar1 = new RegExp("((\||^)" + "(" + var1 + ")" + "(\||$))");
```

and the following code to replace the variable:

```
expression = expression.replace(fullVar1.exec(expression)[1], "\|");
```

Sadly, any pipes that should have been captured as part of the variable are left behind, although non-pipe characters are replaced as they should be.

Example input:

```
expression = "A|~A|B";
var1 = A;
var1 = ~A;
```

Processing:
    fullVar1 = new RegExp("((\||^)" + "(" + var1 + ")" + "(\||$))");
    fullVar1 = new RegExp("((\||^)" + "(" + var1 + ")" + "(\||$))");

```
expression = expression.replace(fullVar1.exec(expression)[1], "\|");
expression = expression.replace(fullVar2.exec(expression)[1], "\|");
```

Expected example output:
    expression == "B";

Current example output:
    expression == "||B";

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Can you write down your expected inputs and outputs?

Comment: Yup! Edited to add. Sorry about that.

Comment: Hi! I've answers the question, but now I see there's an exact duplicate, so I'm marking it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using a string literal you should escape the backslash as well.. This should work:

```
fullVar1 = new RegExp("((\\||^)" + "(" + var1 + ")" + "(\\||$))");
//                       ^                              ^
```

JavaScript generally ignores backslash that don't escape a special character. This can be easily demonstrated like this:

```js
console.log("Backslash is ignored:", "\|")
console.log("Backslash is properly escaped:", "\\|")
```

Comment: Thank you endlessly : ) How silly of me.